# openCV: Saving Mat to vector<vector<int> >

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, save, mat

I have a cv::Mat named myImage which I want to save to an std::vector > named savedVec. This is the code I have written:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myImage.rows; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> row(myImage.cols);
    for (int j = 0; j < myImage.cols; ++j)
    {
        row.push_back(Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getImage().at<uchar>(i, j));
    }
    savedVec.push_back(row);
}
```

My problem now is that somehow `savedVec[0].size()` yields twice the size of myImage.cols, but as they should be the same, shouldn't they?
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: just hope, that you're not *really* calling `Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getImage()`  *per pixel* .

Comment: Actually, I do. What's wrong about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) calling `push_back` appends elements to the vector so it increases the size from the end

so you have size of at least `2*cols` . you should either initialize an empty vector . or use the `[]` operator .

Comment: Not increasing one every time, the size of `vector` usually doubled when needed.